# create custom select field laravel backpack

Tags: php, laravel, select, relationship, laravel-backpack

i am working with laravel backpack, i want a custom select field that actually contains two select fields that depends on each other, i found some suggestions on backpack documentation but it doesn't meet my requirements, what i tried is the following :

```
 $this->crud->addField([
    'type' => 'select_from_array',
    'name' => 'taskable_type',
    
    'label' => 'task type',

    'attribute' => 'taskable_type',
    'options'   => ['project','organization'],
      ]);

      $this->crud->addField([ // select2_from_ajax: 1-n relationship
        'label'                => "Task element", // Table column heading
        'type'                 => 'select2_from_ajax_multiple',
        'name'                 => 'Taskable_id', // the column that contains the ID of that connected entity;
        'entity'               => 'taskable', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute'            => 'taskable_id', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'data_source'          => backpack_url('api/task'), // url to controller search function (with /{id} should return model)
        'placeholder'          => 'Select a task', // placeholder for the select
        'include_all_form_fields' => false, //sends the other form fields along with the request so it can be filtered.
        'minimum_input_length' => 0, // minimum characters to type before querying results
        'dependencies'         => ['taskable_type'], // when a dependency changes, this select2 is reset to null
        // 'method'                    => 'GET', // optional - HTTP method to use for the AJAX call (GET, POST)
    ]);
```

so when i select the organization in the first select, the second select displays me the organizations name and the same think if i select project for projects. but it's not working

Comment: please share the code that in the action api/task, and why it's in api not custom.php?

Comment: ok first i will explain the situation, i have 3 models related with Morphto relationship Task: have the function taskable morphto and Project and Organization have tasks morphMany(), for the api is what i found in backpack documentation i made a route in custom.php as bellow Route::get('api/task', 'TaskController@index'); and in the taskController i should make the logic but it's not receiving any type from the first select (project or orgnization)